# Over-Released NSSet in NSManagedObject

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

I am developing a iPhone app using core data that has a to-many relationship and in one of my classes i have a NSSet property. I am creating an NSSet, assigning to this property and then releasing the object, the problem is a i am getting an **EXC_BAD_ACCESS**.

```
    NSSet *feedSet = [[NSSet alloc] initWithSet:mutableFeedSet];
Signature *signature = (Signature *) [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Signature" inManagedObjectContext:context]; 
signature.site = [feed objectForKey:@"site"];
signature.url = [feed objectForKey:@"url"];
signature.feedList = feedSet;

NSLog(@"%d", [feedSet retainCount]);

[context save:&error];

[feedArray release];
[mutableFeedSet release];
[formatter release];
[feedSet release];
```

when i printed the *feedSet* retain count i realized that the `signature.feedList = feedSet;` wasn't retaining the object, so i removed the `[feedSet release];` and the i got the problem solved... The question is. Why when a assign the feedSet to the feedList property it didn't retained the object?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If `signature.feedList = feedSet;` isn't retaining it, it is because the property is defined as `assign` (not `copy` or `retain`).  Or, if not synthesized, your setter implementation is hosed.

If that isn't the case, you have a stray `autorelease` or `release` somewhere.

Note that `retainCount` is not a very good indicator here;  `autorelease` will not cause the retain count to decrement immediately.

---

Aha! You said `@dynamic feedList;`   Is this a managed object subclass?

`@dynamic` does not provide method implementations.   So, either you have implemented `setFeedList:` or you are subclassing `NSManagedObject` (or their is a superclass involved).

Which is it?

And post the crash backtrace, too, please.

Comment: but that's why i am confused, because i'm using the retain in my property declaration.

Signature.h
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet* feedList;

Signature.m
@dynamic feedList;

Answer (score 0):

Probably Signature is your class, and you have property feedList. If you want to retain the object you have to declare it like this

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSSet* feedList;
```

Comment: but that's how a declared it.

Comment: Than I don't think this is the problem with your property.  NSSet *feedSet = [[NSSet alloc] initWithSet:mutableFeedSet]; - this line means that the objects from mutableFeedSet are retained, so when you first releasing the the mutableFeedSet and then feedSet the objects from them released twice. That's why I'm pretty sure that you over-release some of the objects from that sets (maybe you've released some autorelease one). If I'm right, then commenting the line with [mutableFeedSet release]; and uncommenting the [feedSet release]; would also remove crash.